# Dynamic coloring

Tags: java, gwt, colors

any experience in changing a Widget's (background-) color dynamically? afaik I can only change the CSS style name but as the color is computed, I don't have a chance here?

I found something like
`DOM.setStyleAttribute(mywidget.getElement(), "background", "#FF0000");` but that rather looks nasty.

any ideas?

Comment: Is there some particular reason that setStyleAttribute() is nasty?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the standard way to do it. If you only need to change the background color you could create a function to do this for you:

```
public void setBgColor(String color)
{
    setStyleAttribute(this.getElement(), "background", color)
}
```

or if you want it to work with all widgets:

```
public void setBgColor(UIObject object, String color)
{
    setStyleAttribute(object.getElement(), "background", color);
}
```